# REQUEST_URI is not overridden by using APACHE RewriteRule?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, dns, kohana

**Problem :**

Am using **Kohana**/PHP to develop a hosted website for other companies.
I get the customer to put in a CNAME entry in their DNS server to point to my domain. Eg. http://invites.somecompany.com is pointing to http://www.mydomain.com.

Thus, the **%{HTTP_HOST}** entry on my apache server is 'invites.somecompany.com'

I want to rewrite  http://invites.somecompany.com/invite to http://www.mydomain.com/invites/invite

Even though Apache seems to be doing that, the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is still "/".
The problem is Kohana uses **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** to route the request to the appropriate controller code. In this case, it routes it to the **base** index controller, instead of the '**invites**' controller.

**Facts :**

The Apache mod_rewrite directives i am using (in the .htaccess file) :-

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*invites.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ invites/$1

# For Kohana
RewriteRule .* index.php?kohana_uri=$0 [PT,QSA,L]
```

in the index.php, i do :

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

and i get :

```
'REQUEST_URI' => string '/',
'QUERY_STRING' => string 'kohana_uri=invites/index.php&kohana_uri=invites/invite'
'REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING' => string 'kohana_uri=invites/invite'
```

So the mod_rewrite does not modify the REQUEST_URI ?

**Need :**

```
'REQUEST_URI' => 'invites/invite',
'QUERY_STRING' => string 'kohana_uri=invites/invite',
```

How do I get that?

======================
Edit

Rewrite Log Entries :-

```
strip per-dir prefix: /Users/project/invite -> invite
 applying pattern '^(?:application|modules|system)\b.*' to uri 'invite'
 strip per-dir prefix: /Users/project/invite -> invite
 applying pattern '\.git' to uri 'invite'
 strip per-dir prefix: /Users/project/invite -> invite
 applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'invite'
 rewrite invite -> invites/invite
 add per-dir prefix: invites/invite -> /Users/project/invites/invite
 strip per-dir prefix: /Users/project/invites/invite -> invites/invite
 applying pattern '.*' to uri 'invites/invite'
 rewrite invites/invite -> index.php?kohana_uri=invites/invite
 add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /Users/project/index.php
 strip document_root prefix: /Users/project/index.php -> /index.php
 internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
 strip per-dir prefix: /Users/project/index.php -> index.php
 applying pattern '^(?:application|modules|system)\b.*' to uri 'index.php'
 strip per-dir prefix: /Users/project/index.php -> index.php
 applying pattern '\.git' to uri 'index.php'
 strip per-dir prefix: /Users/project/index.php -> index.php
 applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
 rewrite index.php -> invites/index.php
 add per-dir prefix: invites/index.php -> /Users/project/invites/index.php
 strip per-dir prefix: /Users/project/invites/index.php -> invites/index.php
 applying pattern '.*' to uri 'invites/index.php'
 rewrite invites/index.php -> index.php?kohana_uri=invites/index.php
 add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /Users/project/index.php
 initial URL equal rewritten URL: /Users/project/index.php [IGNORING REWRITE]
```

Comment: That is how mod_rewrite works.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Does this link work if you call it manually?
http://www.mydomain.com/invites/invite

2.) `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com$`needs to be escaped like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$`

3.) `RewriteRule .* index.php?kohana_uri=$0 [PT,QSA,L]` is a infinite loop as index.php fits to the regex `.*`, too.

4.) You need the R flag to redirect the user to invite/ `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ invites/$1 [R=301]`. The `%{REQUEST_URI}` is the same uri as in the browser address bar.

5.) If you don't want to redirect the visitor you could "hack" the kohana system and set `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_GET['myURI'];` in the first line of the index.php if this would be the only option to get it running. The `myURI` can be filled through mod_rewrite as you wish.

Comment: Thanks @mgutt.  5) is what i ended up doing.

Comment: Another interesting tidbit i learned : if you have rewrite rules in the .htaccess file, they get run twice. Alternative is to plugin the rewrite rules into the httpd.conf file, but then i keep getting '400 bad request' errors.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way mod_rewrite works, you can't have it in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` immediately. If you're happy to modify `$_SERVER` (which is sometimes considered a bad idea), how about something like this:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_GET['kohana_uri'];
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Deleted my previous answer as it was flat out wrong. Thanks for the documentation link, learned something new.

Remove the QSA flag:

```
# For Kohana
RewriteRule .* index.php?kohana_uri=$0 [PT,L]
```

[Per the Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags):

> 'qsappend|QSA' (query string append)
>   This flag forces the rewrite engine to
>   append a query string part of the
>   substitution string to the existing
>   string, instead of replacing it. Use
>   this when you want to add more data to
>   the query string via a rewrite rule.

Should have noticed that the first time.

Comment: not true. check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule  "Back-references are $N (N=0..9) identifiers which will be replaced by the contents of the Nth group of the matched Pattern."

Comment: I won't argue with documentation, but I've *never* seen $0 used. Also, you're doing exactly what I said to do in your previous rule. Why the inconsistency?

Comment: i have used $0 before and it works  (its same as in preg_match). The inconsistency is my bad, but even if i make it consistent (by using $0 throughout), the results are still the same.

Comment: Interesting. Any reason to use $0 vs $1 as a starting point? Is it just personal preference?

Comment: i have seen $0 being used elsewhere, so you could say its a preference.